# Left outer join or where statement?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have one query that gives me the total number of records in four different tables on the same date. I filter them for the five pertinent items and exclude one type.

```
SELECT
COUNT (*) AS table_total_filtered
FROM
db.table_1_20150727,
db.table_2_20150727,
db.table_3_20150727,
db.table_4_20150727
WHERE
item LIKE "A" OR item LIKE "B" OR item LIKE "C"
OR item LIKE "D" OR item LIKE "E" AND
type NOT LIKE "Z"
```

I have a second query that gives me the count of rows in my second table. there may be timezone differences in the data so I am pulling the table for three separate days with my target day being the middle date.

```
SELECT
COUNT (*) AS table_2_total
FROM
db2.table_20150726,
db2.table__20150727,
db2.table__20150728
```

The two tables have a common field. The common field has a different name in each table. The field is called ID1 in table_1, table_2, table_3 and table_4. It is called ID2 in table. I want to take the results of the second query and then count how many times the ID matches across both.

```
SELECT
COUNT (*) AS overlap
FROM
db.table_1_20150727,
db.table_2_20150727,
db.table_3_20150727,
db.table_4_20150727,
db2.table_20150726,
db2.table__20150727,
db2.table__20150728
WHERE
item LIKE "A" OR item LIKE "B" OR item LIKE "C"
OR item LIKE "D" OR item LIKE "E" AND
type NOT LIKE "Z" AND
ID1 = ID2
```

As I understand it, this query is not working because the first step takes the count of the first table and is trying to count ID2 which isn't there. Qualifying the fields using the table name also does not appear to work, as the text does not turn blue. I believe that qualifying isn't my problem at this point, what I need to do is make a left join of the results of the first query with the results of the second query and then count where ID1=ID2?

Any help on how to write/approach the appropriate statement to join these two queries and count the number of records where ID1 matches ID2 is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a pretty simple `JOIN` with each of your initial queries as the sources:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) as overlap
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID1
  FROM
    db.table_1_20150727,
    db.table_2_20150727,
    db.table_3_20150727,
    db.table_4_20150727
  WHERE
    item LIKE "A" OR item LIKE "B" OR item LIKE "C"
    OR item LIKE "D" OR item LIKE "E" AND
    type NOT LIKE "Z") AS table_1
JOIN (
  SELECT
    ID2
  FROM
    db2.table_20150726,
    db2.table__20150727,
    db2.table__20150728) as table_2
ON table_1.ID1 = table_2.ID2
```

Note that, in a lot of SQL systems a comma signifies a `JOIN`, but [in BigQuery, the comma actually represents a union](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from):

> **Note**: Unlike many other SQL-based systems, BigQuery uses the comma syntax to indicate table unions, not joins.

This might be why the query you posted above wasn't doing what you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks Danny. I get resources exceeded error. With join each it returns impossible #. I am not clearly explaining my goal. the value returned in your query is > total of table_1. table_2 is a subset of table_1. Table_2 does not include fields needed to identify overlap when table_1 is filtered for the items in WHERE statement. Thus why I am filtering table_1 and then trying to join table_2 to smaller table_1. What I want to happen is A) table_1 filtered down to criteria in WHERE. B) table_2 join with result of A. C) count total where ID1=ID2. An indirect filter of table_2. Thanks again!

Comment: Is it possible that there are duplicate ids in either table?  If so, that could be inflating the count returned, since 2 rows in table_1 could match 2 rows in table_2, causing a count of 4 for a specific id.  You can use `GROUP BY ID1` and `GROUP BY ID2` in the subselects (or `GROUP EACH BY` if necessary) to make sure that there are no duplicates.  Another option could be changing the top-level `COUNT` to `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(table_2.ID2)`, which would only count unique ids.